# Error setting parent state from child using render props: "TypeError: <methodName> is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Using Next.js / React.js I have build a simple app using the setup as shown in the official Next.js tutorial. This means that I am using a `<Layout />` component which is rendered around the different pages.  I show my code below.

Now, using render props I try to set some state of the `<Layout />` component from a child component. When doing this I get the following error:

`TypeError: setLoginToken is not a function`

Can someone explain why this is happening, and show me how to get this to work? I get this error when clicking one of the two buttons on

**My code:**

*Layout component (`components/Layout.js`)*

```
import React from "react";

class Layout extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loginToken: "abc123"
  };

  setLoginToken = newToken => {
    this.setState({ loginToken: newToken });
  };

  render() {
    const { render } = this.props;
    const { loginToken, setLoginToken } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>{render({ loginToken, setLoginToken })}</React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Layout;
```

*index page (`pages/index.js`)*

```
import React from "react";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";

class Index extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Layout
        render={({ loginToken, setLoginToken }) => (
          <div>
            <p>Login token: {loginToken}</p>
            <button onClick={() => setLoginToken("asdfasdf")}>Log in</button>
            <button onClick={() => setLoginToken("")}>Logout</button>
          </div>
        )}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Index;
```

I have also tried the following, with the same result:

```
(setLoginToken) => setLoginToken("asdfasdf")
(setLoginToken) => setLoginToken("")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue come from that you're destructuring `setLoginToken` from `this.state`, instead of `this`.

You can one shot this with

`const { state: { loginToken }, setLoginToken } = this`

Comment: Thanks, guess it happens to the best :'). Glad to have this working, thanks!